# How to upload a css file from local path?

Tags: html, css

I created some lines of CSS for my site and I want to upload it in the stylesheet. The file path's link is:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.css
```

So, I used this code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.css'></link>
```

You would have already guessed that this wouldn't work. Now please tell me how to upload this file to my source code.

Comment: Are you storing the test.css file on the same device that your browser is running?  If so, then it might be a permissions issue either on the file or browsers just not allowed to access that path on a phone (I presume).  Super User might be a better place to ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if you are looking to make this on a global site. The best option is to put the css text in your `style` thing.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to put the full path you just have to put

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css' />
```

if your index.html and test.css in the same file .

Comment: You don't need the ending tag ```</link>``` because it has no innerHTML. You could just do ```<link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'/>```

Comment: yes your are right i will edit that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this path ( Assuming html and css are in the same place):

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "example.css";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply put the solution path where your file does exists

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/yoursolutionpath/css/file.css">
```

be sure you have placed '/' at start because when you route to another page files will not load

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanation. Why would this work, what does this do, how can they apply this knowledge to future situations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`/styles/main.css` then add to template with `<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

```
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('fonts.css');
@import url('forms.css');
@import url('layout.css');
```